# Joint and conditional probabilities with convolutions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

Let $Y,X$ be positive independent continuous random variables with densities $f,g$, and $a<b$ constants. For example $f,g$ could be exponential or gamma densities. Let $Z=X+Y$ be the sum of $Y,X$ so that the distribution of $Z$ is the convolution of $X,Y$; call its density $h$. Consider the joint probability of the events $Z \le b$, and $a < X$.

$$P(Z \le b , a < X)$$

Is there a way to express this joint probability in terms of its densities $f,g,h$ or the respective distribution functions $F,G, H$? For example

$$P(Z \le b , a < X) = P(Z \le b | a < X) P(a < X)$$

with $P(a < X)=1-F(a)$ but I am not sure about how to simplify the first factor. Somebody told me $(1-F(a))H(b-a)$ may be one way, but I could not show it.

Comment: $P(Z \leq b, X>a)$ can be expressed as a double integral of the _joint_ density of $X$ and $Y$. The value of the double integral does not simplify to either of your proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$P(Z< b, a<X) = P(a<X<Y-b) =  \int_{x,y} f(x)g(y)\mathbb 1_{a<x<y-b} dxdy = \int_b^\infty g(y) (\int_{a}^{y-b} f(x)dx)dy = \int_{a+b}^\infty g(y)(F(y-b) - F(a))dy = \int_{a}^\infty g(t+b)(F(t)-F(a))dt$.

I doubt anything would come out of $(1−F())H(−)$ because it seems to assume that $X$ and $Z$ are independent, which is not true.

Comment: Thank you very much. So i understand that there is no  general closed form solution? (Ie no integral)

Comment: I am afraid not.

Comment: In your first equation, shouldn't the inequality be $P(Z<b,a<X) = P(X<b-Y,X>a)  = P(a<X<b-Y)$?

Comment: oops, sorry you are right. You can then proceed similarly, and you would probably get also something of the form of an integral of a density times a cumulative function, and nothing better.

Comment: yes, worked this through. I also noticed that for the case of exponential densities, the indicated relation is true. However it is still possible that this does not hold in general.

Comment: Yes, if $X$ has exponential distribution, there is the magical memoryless property: the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $X>a$ is the same as the distribution of $a+X$. Since $Y$ is independent of $X$, the distribution of $Z$ conditioned on $X>a$ is then the same as the distribution of $a+Z$. So that $(≤,<)=(≤|<)(<) = P(a+Z\leq b)(<) = P(Z\leq b-a)P(a<X)$.